Systemd Failed to resolve unit specifiers "%I" in After and Requires specification
I have a udiskie@$DISPLAY.service that requres panel@@$DISPLAY.service. Both service are started by an X11@$Display.target. I want the udiskie service to start after the panel service. The udiskie@.service contains
[Unit]
Description=udiskie autorun script
After=panel@%I.service
Requires=panel@%I.service

[Service]
Environment=DISPLAY=%I

Type=simple
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/udiskie

I got an error in the journal:
mypc systemd[1360]: /home/q/.config/systemd/user/udiskie@.service:3: Failed to resolve unit specifiers in 'panel@%I.service', ignoring: Invalid slot


You may need to use a double escape strategy as shown here https://askubuntu.com/a/1028902/231221

"dynamic replacement of values" is need here, %I need to be replaced with ":0".

~$ systemd-escape panel@.service
panel\x40.service

If I repalce @ with \x40, same error: Failed to resolve unit specifiers in 'panel\x40%I.service', ignoring: Invalid slot
